# How to make a DIV to occupy the total window height and width with 5 px margin

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to make a DIV to apply total window size with 5px margin but there is some problem with margin property in my code..

```
.outer
{
  background-color:white;
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-right:-5px;
  margin-top:-5px;
  margin-bottom:-5px;
  height:400px;
  width:100%
}
```

Above is my CSS code.. Please help me..

This DIV need to occupy the total height and width of the screen/window size with 5 px margin.

Comment: What is your problem though???

Comment: Not sure why u r using `-5px` rather than just `5px`

Comment: This is not giving Right side margin in IE8 and Left margin in Chrome.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you probably need to set the css elements `html` and `body` to a height and width of 100%. Since they wrap the entire page, the contents in the page cannot include the whole screen if they don't.

Second it's not really a good idea to use `margin` when working with percentages. If you fit a div element with a size equal to the screen and *then* gives it a 5px margin the width in total will be 100% + 5px. That would make it bigger than the screen itself. Why not use `padding` instead? (See [W3's page on the box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)) My suggestion would thus be something like this:

```
html, body, .outer { height: 100%; margin: 0; width: 100%; }
.outer {
 padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to set style for html, just for body. Setting "height: 100%" has no meaning in css. You do not need to set width either. Pading is not the same as margin, for example if you want to use different background color.

Comment: Touché! If you really want to have different background-colors (or want to separate the elements for other reasons) it's probably best to use padding in the body element. As I stated before absolute numbers and relative numbers combined doesn't always add up.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set width, let the margins specify the width.

You need to set margin of body to 0, then change your -5% to 5%.

In addition, you need to set some non-zero padding in your div. For some reason, if you do not set padding, there will be additional margin on top.

Try this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.outer
{
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
  height:400px;
}
```